# determine wether a letter is a vowel or consonant

Tags: string

Ok so my program is supposed to prompt the user to enter a single letter and tell them if the letter is a consonant or vowel and if they enter something other than a single letter, display to them that they have entered an invalid response. Can I use a if-else case and a switch statement at the same time because that's what I'm trying to do here as it seems the easiest.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class VowelConsonant
 {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
   char c1 = input.nextLine().charAt(0);

   if ((c1>= 'a' && c1<= 'z') || (c1>= 'A' && c1<= 'Z')){

      switch(c1){
      case 'a':
      case 'e':
      case 'i':
      case 'o':
      case 'u':
      case 'A':
      case 'E':
      case 'I':
      case 'O':
      case 'U': 
      System.out.println("Letter is a vowel"); break;

      default: 
      System.out.println("Letter is a consonant");
      } 

      }

  }
```

}
}

I don't know how to add the else statement specifying if it's not a letter that the input was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<char> vowels = new ArrayList<char>(Arrays.asList("a", "e", "i", "o", "u");
List<char> consonants = new ArrayList<char>(Arrays.asList("b", "c" ... etc);

char checkChar = Character.toUpperCase(c1);

if (vowels.contains(checkChar)) {
  // it's a vowel
} else if (consonants.contains(checkChar)) {
  // it's a consonant
} else {
  // it's neither
}
```

You'll probably want to make the lists static and final and dump them somewhere as global as possible as the alphabet is unlikely to change.